# How can i set a variable for each player in network

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I make a new game and i implement the network on it, and i need to setup some variables for each player in network to make the combat system betwen them.
I have been serch and i have found on the unity reference the SyncVar' 
but wen i try to do the example its not exist any more on unity reference.
I am using the unity version 5.0.0f4
It give me this error

> 'SyncVar' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

This is my current code

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;



public class menu : MonoBehaviour {

public string IP= "127.0.0.1";
public int Port = 25001;
public bool switchoffnetwork;
public GameObject btnon;
public GameObject btnoff;
[SyncVar]
public static int defence_int;
[SyncVar]
public static int power_int;
[SyncVar]
public static int stamina_int;
[SyncVar]
public static int magic_int;
[SyncVar]
public static int health_int;


public string username = "wizard";

public int idst = 0;

public string ID;
public bool IsClientConnectx= false;
public bool IsServerConnectx= false;

public string clientip;

void OnGUI () 
{
    if (GUI.Button (new Rect (100, 175, 100, 25), "Take stamina")) {
        take_stamina(10);
    }
    if (switchoffnetwork == true) 
    {
        if (Network.peerType == NetworkPeerType.Disconnected) {
            if (GUI.Button (new Rect (100, 100, 100, 25), "Start Client")) {
                Network.Connect (IP, Port);
                IsClientConnectx = true;
            }
            if (GUI.Button (new Rect (100, 125, 100, 25), "Start Server")) {
                Network.InitializeServer (10, Port);
                IsServerConnectx = true;
            }
        } else {
            if (Network.peerType == NetworkPeerType.Client) 
            {
                GUI.Label (new Rect (100, 100, 100, 25), "Player Connected");
                if (GUI.Button (new Rect (100, 125, 100, 25), "Logout")) 
                {
                    Network.Disconnect (250);
                    clientip = Network.player.ipAddress.ToString();
                }
                if (GUI.Button (new Rect (100, 150, 140, 25), "Disconnect Player"))
                if (Network.connections.Length > 0) 
                {
                    Debug.Log("Disconnecting: " + Network.connections[0].ipAddress + ":" + Network.connections[0].port);
                    Network.CloseConnection(Network.connections[0], true);
                }
            }
            if (Network.peerType == NetworkPeerType.Server) {
                GUI.Label (new Rect (100, 100, 100, 25), "Server");
                GUI.Label (new Rect (100, 125, 100, 25), "Connections: " + Network.connections.Length);
                if (GUI.Button (new Rect (100, 150, 100, 25), "Logout")) {
                    Network.Disconnect (250);
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
public void onswitch()
{
    switchoffnetwork = true;
    btnon.SetActive (false);
    btnoff.SetActive (true);
}
public void onswitchbtn()
{
    switchoffnetwork = false;
    btnon.SetActive (true);
    btnoff.SetActive (false);
}

void Update ()
{

    foreach (var ip in Network.connections) {
        Debug.Log("Players Connected-->" + Network.player.ipAddress.ToString());

    }
    //Debug.Log("Players" + Network.player);
    //clientip = Network.connections[1].ipAddress;
    if (Network.peerType == NetworkPeerType.Connecting) {

        if (Network.peerType == NetworkPeerType.Disconnected) {

            Debug.Log ("Player Have disconected" + Network.player.ipAddress.ToString ());
        } else {
            // Allow receiving data again
            Network.isMessageQueueRunning = true;
            // Now the level has been loaded and we can start sending out data to clients
            Network.SetSendingEnabled (0, true);



        }

    }


}

public void take_health(int newhealth)
{
    if (Network.peerType != NetworkPeerType.Server) 
    {
        health_int -= newhealth;
    }
}

public void take_stamina(int newstamina)
{

    if (Network.peerType != NetworkPeerType.Server) 
    {
        stamina_int -= newstamina;
    }
}

public void take_defence(int newdefence)
{
    defence_int = newdefence;
    if (Network.peerType != NetworkPeerType.Server) 
    {
        defence_int -= newdefence;
    }
}

public void take_power(int newpower)
{
    power_int = newpower;
    if (Network.peerType != NetworkPeerType.Server) 
    {
        power_int -= newpower;
    }
}

public void take_magic(int newmagic)
{

    if (Network.peerType != NetworkPeerType.Server) 
    {
        magic_int -= newmagic;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: `SyncVar` is not mentioned at all in your example code. We can't help you without you giving us a [mcve].

Comment: @Shadow tank you for the replay in fact i haved take of and just not make atention to it but i haved try like the edit code

Comment: implement`NetworkBehaviour ` not  `MonoBehaviour `

Comment: Alternatively use a `[ClientRpc]` which is executed on all clients and set the value(s) there. Especially having a lot of values this is often saving more bandwidth since syncvar afaik are transfered one by one - but I might be wrong on this

Answer (score 0):

On the Gamecontroler add the networking component 
And the nerworking hud

On your player add the networking identity